# Chrome extension background page inactive makes the extension run on 2 clicks

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have an extension which runs on a background page, the browserAction icon requires 2 clicks at max few seconds apart for the extension to start running background.js so I tried to see what's the issue, with chrome://extensions page loaded which states for my extension:Background page inactive. When I click one time the state changes to background page active and then the next click actually runs the extension, I couldn't see what's the issue, I use `chrome.runtime.reload()` at a couple of places, maybe that's the issue but what's the solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A background page can become inactive if it's declared as an Event page ( `"persistent": false` in the manifest).

Which probably means that you haven't set it up correctly if events are only handled after causing them twice.

**Obvious solution:** drop `"persistent": false` from the manifest. This is not recommended unless you use things that cannot work with Event pages (currently, mainly `webRequest` API)

**Proper solution:** see if your background script can be [made into a proper Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_migration).

Comment: Cool. A great solution is to use a "connection" as described in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging